# Alignment on a println for a table

Tags: java, alignment

I'm sure there are plenty of questions like this that have been answered here but I couldn't find the answer I needed. I need to right align 2 out of 4 columns for a table. The first 2, from left to right, are supposed to be left aligned and the others are supposed to be right. I have read that - will left align while the default is right. I have tried with and without that option to no avail. Below is a snippet of the code. Let me know if I need to include more. Again, I have added and removed the - but it hasn't properly aligned the text either way.

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
                System.out.printf("%-10d%-12s%42.2f%10d%n",input.nextInt(), input.next(), initialCost = input.nextDouble(), itemCount = input.nextInt());
                inventory += itemCount;
                totalCost += initialCost * itemCount;
            }
```

And here is some of the output I am getting:

```
#         Product                                                          Cost        Stock
1         Bread - Sticks, Thin, Plain                                      3.91        54
2         Towel Multifold                                      7.68         9
3         Soup - Boston Clam Chowder                                      2.18        55
4         Bread - Roll, Soft White Round                                      5.22        59
5         Spinach - Packaged                                      4.20        11
```

Thanks in advance!
-Thomas

Comment: Try `%-10d%-32s%12.2f%10d%n`

Comment: That worked! Can you explain?

Comment: Your second column (which contains `Product`) contains `String`(s) that are longer than 10 characters. I increased the second column width to 32 and decreased the third by the same amount.